# Can't find gl_MultiTexCoord0 replacement

Tags: java, opengl, shader, lwjgl

I'm making an OpenGL game with LWJGL and just implemented successfully vertex attributes along with VBO's, my problem now is that I have a small UI that is based on slick-util and it doesn't render the textures as it should be, I guess it must be how slick passes the texture coordinates to shaders. Right now I'm passing the textures coordinates to vertex shader through a vertex attribute like this:

```
pass_TextureCoord = in_TextureCoord;
```

When I change to this:

```
pass_TextureCoord = gl_MultiTexCoord0;
```

All 3d things loose their textures and the UI returns to normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gl_MultiTexCoord0` will only work using the fixed-function texture coordinate pointer functions. Without seeing how slick-util is implemented it is almost impossible to tell you what the correct behavior should be. If you have an option, however, you should favor using generic vertex attribute pointers; `glTexCoordPointer (...)` is deprecated.

Nevertheless, if `glTexCoordPointer (...)` is used, the pointer applies to the active texture unit. Make sure you set the active texture unit to `GL_TEXTURE0` before using slick-util to set the texture coordinate pointer if you are expecting `gl_MultiTexCoord0` to reference your texture coordinates.

Comment: So there is any way of joining together the UI from slick-util and the vertex attributes?

Comment: @user2054583: In the worst case, you might consider using a different vertex shader when rendering slick-util UI things.